# Android Numeric Keypad

Tags: android, cordova, android-edittext

I've got my app working, but can't get the keypad to only show numeric keys (including decimals). I'm using phonegap, so I don't know if that's what's causing the issue, but I've tried adding:

```
<EditText android:numeric="decimal" />
```

into both my AndroidManifest.xml and the activity_main.xml but no luck.

I'm thinking I need to change something inside phonegap, because my activity_main.xml only shows the hello world string and not the other components of my app.

**EDIT**

Here's the "activity_main.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

  <EditText   
    android:inputType="number">
  </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now here's the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourappname.yourappname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<EditText android:inputType="phone" android:numeric="decimal"></EditText>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code?

Comment: did you try using this with your EditText `android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"` Try using `number` `numberSigned` or `numberDecimal` as per your need. And also provide layout params to your `EditText`

Comment: Thanks guys. I just simply changed my html from <input type="textbox"> to <input type="number">

Answer (score 1):

Hii you haven't given height and width to your editext.so it will not be shown in your layout file.As far as input is concerned,inputType=number will popup Number pad.Use below code for EditText.

```
   <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/edittext"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number"/>
```